# Is there a way to display locations without Google Maps? - android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2, android-location

I want to display locations but not necessarily on a map. I just need a widget with a white background that can display Location objects. Is there anything like that available?

Comment: do you want a location in form of a string(text)?

Comment: No, I want do display them relative to each other. Similarly to how it would look on Google Maps with Markers.

Comment: So you want to show the current location on the map but not Google Maps? I'm right?

Comment: Yes. I want to do something like that, although I want to display other points than the current location as well.

Comment: you should use Mapbox , mapbox is alternate of google map. and only location you can use Geocoder https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder

Comment: Google map free for Android... Why you're not preferring!? Other maps depends with thrid parties...

Comment: Google static map api available but it's payable service